# How to create multiple Threads in OCaml

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, functional-programming, ocaml

The function `run_counter` may create m threads, each counting from 0 to n:

```
let run_counters m n = 
            let rec count x = 
              if x > n then ()
              else ( Printf.printf "%d" x;
            Thread.yield ();
            count (x+1) ) 
            in 
            Thread.create count 0
```

However I don't know how to create multiple Threads, I tried to write a recursive call with a counter m but I get an Error:`This expression has type t but an expression was expected of type unit`

```
let run_counters m n = 
            let rec count x = 
              if x > n then ()
              else ( Printf.printf "%d" x;
            Thread.yield ();
            count (x+1) ) 
            in 
            let rec inc n =
            if n = 0 then () else
            inc (n-1);
            Thread.create count 0;
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Also your code formatting is horrendous, which can easily lead to masking bugs. You should look into using a tool like ocp-indent or ocamlformat to format the code automatically if you can't be bothered to do so manually.

Comment: Can you show the exact error? It's supposed to show you which expression is ill-typed.

Comment: When I add your code I have a syntax error by the way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so your function is a bit of mess, first there is a syntax error:

```
let run_counters m n = 
            let rec count x = 
              if x > n then ()
              else ( Printf.printf "%d" x;
            Thread.yield ();
            count (x+1) ) 
            in 
            let rec inc n =
            if n = 0 then () else
    >>>>>   inc (n-1);
            Thread.create count 0;
```

At location `>>>>>`, there is a `let rec inc...` without an `in ...` following it, you just interrupt the expression with a semicolon. If we replace it with `in`, then the function `inc` is reported as being unused.

Let's take a step back for a minute, and write each functions separately, this will become a lot easier than trying to do everything at once. Also, you can test individual functions more easily.

#### Do something `n` times

First, write a function that calls some function `f` for its side-effects, `n` times. We could write a recursive version (and if that's homework, you probably are asked to do that), but OCaml has for loops so let's use them:

```
let rec call_n_times f n =
  for i = 0 to (n-1) do
    f i
  done
```

For example, this prints number from 0 to 2, and returns nothing (unit type):

```
# call_n_times (fun n -> Printf.printf "%d\n" n) 3;;
0
1
2
- : unit = ()
```

In fact, this example is what your threads are supposed to do (what a coincidence).

#### Print increasing numbers

In our future tests we will be calling different counters, so let's add a parameter that is the name of the counter:

```
# let print_n name = call_n_times (fun i -> Printf.printf "%s %d\n" name i);;
val print_n : string -> int -> unit = <fun>
```

As you can see, we name `print_n` the partial application of `call_n_times` with a function, the remaining argument `n` is implicit here.

```
# print_n "test" 3;;
test: 0
test: 1
test: 2
```

#### Spawn 1 thread

The next step is writing a function that just spawns one thread, and ask it to execute `print_n` (so it needs an integer argument) with the name of the thread.

Using partial application as previously, this is:

```
# let spawn_counter name = Thread.create (print_n name);;
val spawn_counter : string -> int -> Thread.t = <fun>
```

For example:

```
# spawn_counter "single-thread" 3;;
- : Thread.t = <abstr>

# Thread.yield();;
single-thread: 0
single-thread: 1
single-thread: 2
- : unit = ()
```

#### Name a thread from a number

We need also an intermediate function that produces a name (a string) from a number, let's quickly write that:

```
# let thread_name = Printf.sprintf "<thread %d>";;
val thread_name : int -> string = <fun>
```

#### Spawn `m` threads

Now we can write `spawn_m_n_counters`:

```
# let spawn_m_n_counters m n =
    call_n_times (fun i -> spawn_counter (thread_name i) n) m;;
val spawn_m_n_counters : int -> int -> unit = <fun>

# spawn_m_n_counters 3 5;;
- : unit = ()
```

#### Refactor

You have a basic skeleton of your functions, but I left `Thread.yield()` out of the functions.

Also, you want to *collect* all the spawn threads so that you can `join` them. That means you need a `call_n_times` that collects the output of the function. See if you can write that recursively.